# Make LAMP Server public

Tags: kubuntu, 14.10, lamp

I installed a LAMP server in my computer to try some php and html scripts and I want to know if I can make those files public so I can see them from other computer with other internet conection. How can I do it?

Comment: Are we talking about computers in the same network OR users from the internet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## A few steps to follow in order to be sure:

Check IP on the server machine, look for the adapter that connects the machine to the internet (eth0 will probably be the one, albeit it sure can be ethX depending on your configuration)

```
sudo ifconfig
```

Try pinging the IP you found out via ifconfig. Be sure that you are pinging from a computer who is not in the same network as your server, just to be sure.

```
ping XYZ
```

## You didn't get a ping?

I suppose you are connecting your server machine via your home router. Meaning you have to configure it to forward the port you set your apache at. Or just enable your local server as DMZ (which I can tell is not a safe thing to do, but works adhoc).

Sadly port forwarding looks different for each router, you need to find out how to do that for your specific hardware.

## You got a ping? You are ready to go

Getting a ping back means your machine has public IP and is visible over the internet. LAMP apache doesn't require any configuration to work as you wish it to. Just enter the server IP into your browser, perhaps add a port if you set up apache on a different one than 80, eg.:

```
http://XYZ:8080/
```

Comment: How can I know at which port I set apache? I followed this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wrZQDYa-9NM

Comment: This will show you the apache port configuration file. Listen XXX will occur many times, where XXX is the port apache is running at. 
    sudo cat /etc/apache2/ports.conf